# Is it really legal to turn right from the lane nearest and to the right of the yellow line into the lane nearest and to the right of the yellow line?

Tags: traffic

Is it really legal (traffic law in Alberta) to turn right from the lane nearest and to the right of the yellow line into the lane nearest and to the right of the yellow line, as shown in the following image? Shouldn't the car turn from the lane nearest and to the right of the yellow line into the lane furthest and to the right of the yellow line instead?  I apologize for not being able to share the link  that contains the image because it's part of a password protected online video. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the car cannot use the rightmost lane of the bottom road?

Comment: @PMF He's asking about turning from the leftmost lane of one road to the leftmost lane of the other road.

Comment: @PMF I think it's predicated on the fact that the rightmost lane is blocked, i.e. by a legally parked vehicle. This situation arises when some roads use both lanes during rush hours, but allow parking that blocks the right lane during off-peak times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Probably not.

I'm not sure about Canadian traffic laws, but I know that changing lanes while turning is illegal where I live. If you turn from the leftmost lane travelling in your direction on one road into the same lame of the new road, you're remaining in your lane. If everyone remains in their lane, traffic can flow smoothly around the corner. If people can change their lanes while turning, then you open the door for traffic chaos as cars weave around each other while turning. It's not safe.

Comment: In the US, this is one of those things that varies widely by state. For example, in [California](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/handbook/california-driver-handbook/navigating-the-roads/) (Left turn from a two-way street), a left turn can change lanes if not marked.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!